# Better to check for affirmative or negative condition in PHP (or does it matter)

Tags: php

Comparing these two bits of code:

```php
if (isset(x)){
  // do the is-set thing
}else{
  // do the not-set thing
}
```

```php
if(!isset(x)){
  // do the not-set thing
}else{
  // do the set thing
}
```

Aside from readability (I find the first more straightforward) is there any significant difference between the two?

Comment: If you check for true or false value is not difference and in this cases I use this rule: first I write the condition with less code and in else statement the more code so I don't need to scroll more and more line of code for read the else condition.

Comment: Check this https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/336502/does-if-else-optimization-in-php-have-any-effect